# Maven + Tomcat + Eclipse Java hotswap

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, hotswap

I have a problem. I start Tomcat in JPDA mode, and after that I execute:

```
mvn tomcat:stop tomcat:undeploy war:inplace tomcat:inplace
```

After which I connect to remote Java app from Eclipse. All works ok, I'm able to change some code and hot swap works.

When I add method/change parameters I redeploy the app:

```
mvn tomcat:stop tomcat:undeploy war:inplace tomcat:inplace
```

After which when I reconnect to the remote java app again, only now when I change any file (for example, placing a space or removing space, save) I get an error that code cannot been swapped out - `"Hot Code Replace Failed - add method not implemented"`.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like choosing plexus-compiler-eclipse as compiler is solving this problem, I'm testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM only supports hot swap for changes to the method body. For other changes, like changing the parameters or adding new methods, consider choosing JRebel which supports these.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) JVM agent should work better.  For one, it has the new parameters and methods feature that is lacking with current JVM hot code replace.  I recently got this setup and verified that new methods in existing classes work as expected.