# Maven multi-module doesn't reload resources

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

We are having some issue with Maven multi-module project. We have divided our project into some Maven modules. Each module is packaged as WAR and each one depends upon the other one.

Actually our architect designed this structure. But now we are facing a problem that is very annoying. JSP classes not reloading instantly. For example I am changing only one html element's class , I have to re-run application to see changes.  Before dividing process it was ok , all java classes and JSPs were reloadable instantly. But now only java classes are reloaded not resources. We are using tomcat-7 maven plugin as container and run application as `tomcat7:run-war` goal. I will appreciate if any suggestion that helps me how to solve this problem and to mirror changes on JSP instantly to user interface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: You might be interested in that here a hot swap discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548506/hotswaping-code-into-mvndebug-tomcatrun

Comment: I am using Intellij. Also I added jrebel plugin and configured it succesfully-I think-. But no result.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tomcat-7:run-war` will start tomcat using a packaged war file.
Did you try to run `tomcat-7:run` instead ?

Comment: Unable to run tomcat7:run.We have used to use it before dividing process. Nowi e are using overlay feature .